# Problem about rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,+,*)$ be a ring so that $(x+y)^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}$ $\forall\ x, y \in R$. Prove that

A)$xy=-yx$ $\forall\ x, y \in R$

B)$x^{2}+x^{2}=0$   $\forall\ x, y \in R$ and $x+x=0\ \forall\ x, y \in R$

I have already proved A) and $x^{2}+x^{2}=0$   $\forall\ x, y \in R$ and for the last part of B I had that:

$x^{2}+x^{2}=0 \Rightarrow\ (x+x)^{2}=0$ but I don´t know if this implies that $x+x=0$

So I would really appreciate your help for the last part of B

Comment: If your ring has a unit $1$, then you can use part (A), setting $y=1$.

Comment: If it doesn't have a unit, the result is false (try a zero ring on three elements).

Comment: But how can I know that the ring has unit 1? Do I need to prove it?

Comment: They bring up the question of $1$, because there are two different conventions about what the word "ring" means. Check your definition.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+xy+yx$ , then by our assumption $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2\Rightarrow xy+yx=0$ That is exactly what you wanted to show.note that taking $x=y$ immediately implies second part.it seems to me that ring $R$ ought to have multiplicative identity $1_R$.assuming that let $y=1_R$ then by first part $1x=-x1$ thus $x+x=0$

Comment: thanks a lot!!!!!! and one last thing: do I need to prove that the ring has unit 1?

Comment: In some undergrad type textbooks they assume all their rings contain identity to begin with. im not sure if that statement still holds if we put the assumption of having identity aside.well i dont know any counterexample of top of my head.